# Byte calculation giving unexpected answer

Tags: java, type-conversion, integer, byte, arithmetic-expressions

I was just playing around with some code and was curious about the following result:

```
byte b = 50;
b *= 50; 
System.out.println(b);
```

The output I get is `-60`.

Why is this the case? Also, why don't I get a compile error as this seems to be a form of implicit type conversion (i.e. to an int).

For example, I cannot write the following:

```
b = b * 50;
```

Comment: A java byte can hold values from -128 to 127. So of course if you try to put 50*50 into it you will get an overflow and not the correct result.

Comment: *why don't I get a compile error* -- because if the language defined the result of the calculation of `a op b` in `a op= b` to be widened to `int` for smaller integral types, priot to assignment back into `a`, the `op=` operator would be unusable for those types, and thus not exist in the language.